# How to get variable value from another js file

Tags: javascript, variables, global

I've JavaScript file named `Second.js` which contains variable named `page`.

Second.js:

```
var page = 1;
```

How can I retrieve that value, i.e `page`, from another JavaScript named `one.js`?

Comment: Load `Second.js` first or load `one.js` first and use your variable from `Second.js` after load of `Second.js` (Like page load or button click)

Comment: If you have multiple files with multiple cross dependencies, then I suggest you read up on Require.js, it's an excellent framework for making js modular

Comment: I've tried global.page and window.page but its not working

Comment: @prabinbadyakar Give us example of both js files and html file

Comment: @Epsilon Sorry i just need that logic. My task is, I want to show alert"Please Read and Answer the questions " only when user enter for the first time but once the user fills some answers and skip , when he join the link again , he shouldnt be able to see that alert . So i'm trying to get answered question(length) from second page, if its greater than 0 then i wil add condition in my first page .

Comment: @prabinbadyakar I still cannot understand whole concept but I think you need to use Cookie (or session) to save clients status (that he/she was here before). Otherwise message will be prompted after page refresh.

Comment: @Epsilon thanks. Will work on it .

Answer (score 3):

An other way to get a value from another .js file is saving the variable in the browser:

```
a.js
var myemail="xyz@gmail.com";
localStorage.setItem("email",myemail);
```

Now this variable is saved in browser. If we want to get this variable in another file we use:

```
b.js
var x=localStorage.getItem("email");
alert(x) // output=xyz@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want variable visibility between different scripts you can attach the variable on the `window`. e.g:

**script 1:**

```
window.page = 1;
```

**script 2:**

```
alert(page);
```

Make sure you don't use very simple variable names (e.g such as `page`) to avoid possible collisions. A good practice is to attach an array of your application name on the window and work with that, being sure that you'll not affect anything on the "global scope". e.g:

```
window.MY_APP = {
  page: 1,
  foo: 'bar',
  whatever: [1, 2, 3],
  example: {
    name: 'john',
    surname: 'smith'
  }
};
```

Comment: `var page = 1;` is the same as `window.page = 1` given the former is stated outside of a function

Comment: @AlexanderBrevig: *Almost* the same, you can `delete` the latter but not the former. :-)

Answer (score 0):

All JavaScript on the page executes in the same overall environment, so if `page` is a global in `Second.js`, you can use it from any other JavaScript you load on the page. E.g.:

```
<script src="Second.js"></script>
<script src="SomeOtherFile.js"></script>
```

Provided, again, that `page` is a global, you can use it from `SomeOtherFile.js` (just referencing it as `page`, no qualifiers).

Or even:

```
<script src="Second.js"></script>
<script>
    alert(page); // "1"
</script>
```

If `page` *isn't* a global, then you'll have to modify `Second.js` in some way to make the `page` variable or value available to other scripts. You can do that by making it global, of course, or you can use an Asynchronous Module Definition loader to avoid having bunches of globals around and manage dependencies. (AMD may be overkill for what you're doing, or not, we don't have a lot of context here.)

Comment: I have code inside jQuery ready function like `$(function(){..` on both pages. I was able to get the code (var) from the first page if I put the code before the ready handler but I was not able to do it if I had `var` something inside the ready handler in the first page. To help with that on the first page instead of using `var something` I used `window.something` and I was able to access the code that was on the first page. Any comments on that? Thanks. I found this out the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

They both have to be included into the same HTML file. Make sure both are in, and loaded, and then it is as if all your javascript exists in one single, massive, JS file!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing this: load the scripts in the order you want to access them, or don't start executing your scripts until the page the has loaded (recommended, as this ensures that everything is definitely loaded!).
Either way you can reference your variables as if they were in the same file - you do not need to re-declare them with 'var'.